# Umbraco get media url

Tags: umbraco

I have a document type with a media picker property. The property have alias "bannerimage". Now i am trying to get hold of the image url in my template.

I am using the GetMediaURL-method to fetch the image url, but all i get is an error. The trace gives me `The type or namespace name 'GetMediaUrl' does not exist in the namespace 'Umbraco' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Here is my code

```
<umbraco:Macro runat="server" language="cshtml">
<img src='@Umbraco.GetMediaUrl(DynamicModel.bannerimage, "uploadedFile")' alt="Banner"/>
</umbraco:Macro>
```

Umbraco version is 4.11.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, GetMediaUrl was an Umbraco5 method. As such, I don't think it exists in the 4.11 dlls.

umbraco.library.GetMedia or Library.MediaById should be accessible, though.

Comment: GAHH why is the Umbraco documentation so... non existing? Thank you, GetMedia worked.